# Remove invalid N-Quads from file in Jena

Tags: rdf, jena, n-quads

I have a file containing N-Quads (using the schema.org vocabulary) and I want to load it into a TDB RDF-store, using Apache Jena's command line tools. The command that I'm using is:

```
tdbloader --loc <rdf_store_location> <file_to_load>
```

But during the loading, I got an error:

> [line: 769293, col: 154] Illegal unicode escape sequence value: \" (0x22)

I also ran the validation tool from Jena command line tools:

```
riot --validate <file_to_load>
```

and indeed, there are at least 30 errors/warnings similar to that:

> Bad IRI

> The path contains a segment /../ not at the beginning of a relative reference, or it contains a /./ These should be removed

**Is there a way to ignore invalid N-Quads, or to delete them, by using the command line tools (Jena or if you have knowledge of other)?**

Otherwise the only option would be to do a script to remove the invalid characters. But besides the file is huge (60 GB), I guess this is very prone to errors.

Comment: It is good to check beore loading because of bad or unsuitable data.

N-Quads is line based.  Skip a triple is remove that line. Use the text editting tools of your OS : on Linux, "sed", "perl" etc will be able to find and skip lines in error or fix them.

Comment: Thank you, @AndyS! I will remove the bad lines then